# Como apagar um repositório existente com Git?

Tags: git

[image: Preciso apagar este repositório antes de criar um novo]

Preciso de ajuda para apagar este repositório e para criar um novo, pois toda vez que tento criar aparece essa mensagem. E não consigo enviar o meu projeto para o github. Detalhe: Já exclui ele no github.

Comment: Você pode criar um outro repositório em outra pasta também. Qual a encrenca para não fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só apagar a pasta .git que está dentro de /site e usar o comando `git init` novamente. Lembrando que dependendo do seu ambiente a pasta pode não aparecer pois ela é oculta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado broder, já consegui!!!